# Can I use a logical OR operator to test two conditions in if statement?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, if-statement, awt

I have a start button and a popup menu option that do the same thing. Is it possible to test both buttons in the same if statement or do I have to write two separate if statements for them?

I want to do something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            // The start button and the popup start menu option
            if (e.getSource() == start)||(e.getSource() == startPopup){
                new Thread() {
                    @Override 
                    public void run() {
                        GreenhouseControls.startMeUp();
                    }
                }.start();
```

Comment: *"..or do I have to write two separate if statements for them?"*  The most common approach is to write two separate **`ActionListener` objects!**

Comment: I believe it's more normal to have just ONE ActionListener object, but only have it listen to those objects that you need it to listen to.  In this case, there'd be no `if` in the `actionPerformed` method; but this `ActionListener` would be listening to the "start" button and the "popup start" menu option.  That makes it much more flexible - you don't need to rewrite the `ActionListener` if you decide to do something like add a toolbar button with the same action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem here is the brackets. An `if` statement is of the form:

```
if (condition)
   body
```

Currently you've got

```
if (condition1) || (condition2)
   body
```

which isn't valid. You just want:

```
if (e.getSource() == start || e.getSource() == startPopup)
```

Or potentially extracting out the commonality:

```
Object source = e.getSource();
if (source == start || source == startPopup)
```

You can add *extra* parentheses if you really want:

```
Object source = e.getSource();
if ((source == start) || (source == startPopup))
```

... but there has to be just *one* overall expression in parentheses.

Comment: I thought I tried that version already! I guess I had it wrong. Thanks.